# jQuery - Shuffle between images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Im trying to make a `shuffle` between **5 images** I have in my template. Currently what I have is that I `shuffle` between **5 images** and I show **one of them randomly**.

*My HTML*

```
<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb1">
  <img src="image-1.png" class="none" />
</div>
<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb2">
  <img src="image-2.png" class="none" />
</div>
<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb3">
  <img src="image-3.png" class="none" />
</div>
<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb4">
  <img src="image-4.png" class="none" />
</div>
<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb5">
  <img src="image-5.png" class="none" />
</div>
```

*My CSS*

```
.none {display:none;}
```

*My JS*

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    get_random_bulb();
    function get_random_bulb() {
        var a = (parseInt(Math.random() * 4));
        $(".lightbulb img.block").removeClass("block").addClass("none");
        $(".lightbulb:eq(" + a + ") img").removeClass("none").addClass("block");
    }
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3500 - 500)) + 500;
    setInterval(function () {
        get_random_bulb();
    }, rand);
  });
```

This works fine as it randomly picks one image and display it, but I want to have a more styled and better shuffle. Like the picture below:

[image]

Where the last 3 image is showing and when new image is randomly picked it goes to end of the list and the first one goes away.

*I hope I have managed to explain what I mean*

Comment: So you want to show three pictures, and then add a randomly selected image that isn't currently shown to the end of the list as the first element is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with this: https://jsfiddle.net/mehmetb/brbj8db6/

HTML

```
<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb1">
  <img class="shuffle-image" />
</div>

<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb2">
  <img class="shuffle-image" />
</div>

<div class="lightbulb" id="bulb3">
  <img class="shuffle-image" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.shuffle-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var shuffleList = [
  'https://dummyimage.com/90x90/ccc/000000.jpg&text=1',
  'https://dummyimage.com/90x90/ccc/000000.jpg&text=2',
  'https://dummyimage.com/90x90/ccc/000000.jpg&text=3',
  'https://dummyimage.com/90x90/ccc/000000.jpg&text=4',
  'https://dummyimage.com/90x90/ccc/000000.jpg&text=5'
];

var $lightBulbs = $(".lightbulb");

function shuffle() {
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (3500 - 500)) + 500;

  for(var i=0;i<$lightBulbs.length;++i) {
    var $img = $lightBulbs.eq(i).children('img');

    $img.attr('src', shuffleList[i]);
  }

  //Put the first array element to the last
  shuffleList.push(shuffleList.shift());

 //Each call will set a random delay between shuffles
 setTimeout(function() {
   shuffle();
 }, rand);
}

shuffle();
```

Comment: Thanks @Mehmet, But This does the same I had earlier, How can I have the other 2 as well? As you can see, In my shuffle gif image, I show 3 images, where the last image is the new shuffled picked image and first image just goes away

Comment: Have a look at the fiddle (and the answer) again please :)

Comment: Thanks @Mehmet, Works perfect :)

Comment: only one question that I just saw. In your example, you have 5 images (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and when it shuffles, it doesn't actually shuffle between (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) and choose a number to show for next image, it basically goes with the order (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ect) and not 1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 5, 3, 4, 1. How can I fix it?

Comment: Works like a charm @Mehmet :) much appreciated :)

Comment: You are welcome @user6589814 :) If you really want to thank me again, you can give me an upvote too;  I'm kind of curious about the next stackoverflow privilege :)

Comment: haha sorry @Mehmet, didnt know I could upvote on my own. But again Thanks, maybe a upvote for me too :)

Comment: There you go :)